# React native error: Error: watch EMFILE

Tags: react-native

I just started my 1st react native app following this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/99473/introducing-react-native-building-apps-javascript

However when I run a build I get the following: is it important?

```
[5:24:30 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[5:24:30 PM] <START> Crawling File System
 ERROR  watch EMFILE
{"code":"EMFILE","errno":"EMFILE","syscall":"watch"}
Error: watch EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1172:11)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1198:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/Users/me/PhpstormProjects/foo/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:144:20)
    at Walker.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMFILE is an error that occurs when too many files are open by a single process. I had the same problem with a different tech stack this week. You can avoid the error by increasing the limit of open files using the `ulimit` command.

```
ulimit 4096 # for instance
```

You should probably try to figure out why so many files are open. Maybe your watch task is watching files inside `node_modules` folder or the like.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't have watchman installed I think or running its process.

Comment: According to the sources [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1d1386e7355fcd269aefea415e3a174b529917da/packager/react-packager/src/FileWatcher/index.js#L21) react-native will use watchman if available in the path which seems to be the preferred option. Try installing it (`brew install watchman`) and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Also looking at the packager [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/packager.sh#L16) they are already setting the limit to 4096. If using watchman gives you the same error you probably have too many js files in your working directory for some reason...

Comment: After installing brew still gives the same error. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: I am just using the default react native project for "react-native": "^0.11.4"

Comment: Running ulimit 4096 # for instance doesn't help either. I'm on a new mac pro.

Answer (score 18):

I ran into the same issue updating to macOS Sierra, however, it turned out that watchman was to blame. Looking through the logs I stumbled upon numerous [odd permission issues](https://www.karltarvas.com/2016/10/10/react-native-error-watch-emfile.html).

As covered on [github/facebook/react-native#9943](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9943), reinstalling watchman solves the issue.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/
brew uninstall watchman
brew install watchman
```

Comment: I had this error earlier on my Mac Sierra. Uninstalled watchman and installed it again and the error got fixed. But now, the Hot reloading was not working. Executing the above command, fixed the hot reloading and the changes started reflecting immediately.

Comment: I struggeled with this for hours! Thanks!

Comment: I believe `brew reinstall watchman` does the same in one line.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering this issue on MAC OS (Sierra) and the way to solve it was by following the steps below on terminal:

`launchctl limit maxfiles`

It may show 256 as the lower limit. The following command will change the limits.

`sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 unlimited`

Next you also want to uninstall react-native and reinstall it so you get a version which works better with Sierra. You also want to update Homebrew and install the current version of watchman.

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-cli
brew update
brew install watchman`

Credit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10088

Answer (score -2):

Run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` Maybe help.